# Sending xml data to other domain(cross domain) Using java

Tags: java, httpclient

I am trying to send the xml formatted data to other server means cross-domain using java like HttpClient. I have checked other post in stackoverflow and mkyong but nothing worked for me. IN mkyong this post

[http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/][1] is working but i do not know how to send data without using parameter.

Please guide to move forward.
Thank you for your help.

**Edit**

I am using this code and it working for me.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
 import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

 public class workingCode {
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException       {


  try {
      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    // add header
    post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

        List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cn", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "12345"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        System.out.println("Response Code : "     + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"    Response StatusLine : "     + response.getStatusLine());

        InputStreamReader isp = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(isp);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
} catch (IllegalStateException e ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        cpe.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException ie) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        ie.printStackTrace();
} 
}
}

This is working but i need to send the data like this.

StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data, HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
post.setEntity(entity);
```

and when i do this by changing the url to client url it is failing but when do this using javascript it is failing by saying "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized".

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
      HttpResponse response = null;
      try {    

            String url = ResourceBundle.getBundle("resourses").getString("url");

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            // add header
            post.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(StringXMLDATA, HTTP.UTF_8);

            entity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            entity.setChunked(true);
            post.setEntity(entity);

            response = client.execute(post);
            System.out.println("Response Code : "     + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"    Response StatusLine : "     + response.getStatusLine());

            InputStreamReader isp = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(isp);

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("line : "+line);
                result.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println("Result :   " + result);
    }catch (Exception cpe) {
        System.out.println(cpe);
    }finally { 
        client.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
    }
```

FOR this code you need to Add 3 Jar whuch name  i am giving below and you can download these jars from this link http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

### JARs NEEDS

commons-logging-1.1.jar
http-client-4.3.1.jar
http-core-4.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

check out link http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/docs/files/jquery-ba-postmessage-js.html

hope this will help you.